# Resezing images not working - Imagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

first of all here is my code:

```
<?php     
  public function uploadFiles($name,$gallery_code,$uncategorized = true) {
   foreach($_FILES[$name]["error"] as $key=>$error) {
    if(!$error) {
     $photo_name = $_FILES[$name]["name"][$key]; 
     $tmp_name = $_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"][$key];

      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,showConfigValues("img_source_admin")."/".$photo_name);

 $insert = $this->_mysqli->insert("photos",array(
                                            "id" => "",
                                            "photos_name" => $photo_name,
                                            "photos_description" => "",
                                            "title_photo" => "n",   
                                            "show_description_in_photos" => "y",
                                            "gallery_code" => $gallery_code));
 if($uncategorized) {
  //Resizing    
  $file = ''.showConfigValues("img_source_admin").'/'.$photo["photos_name"];
  $src = realpath($file);

  if(!list($w, $h) = getimagesize($src)) echo "Unsupported picture type!";

    $picture = new Imagick(realpath(showConfigValues("img_source_admin").'/'.$photo["photos_name"]));

    $picture->resizeImage(684, 457, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    $picture->writeImage(realpath(showConfigValues("img_source_admin").'/'.$photo["photos_name"]));
    $picture->clear();
    $picture->destroy(); 


$thumb->writeImage(showConfigValues("img_source_admin").'/'.$photo["photos_name"]);
 } 
 } 
 }
}
?>
```

When I want to upload any images, the **resize** doesn't work and when I am uploading multiple images only 1 image is saved in database.
I want to save new image(resized image) with the same name. This code for resize works only when I am not uploading any images(the code isn't in the same file).

Thank you for your help